# Testing with Require js in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, requirejs, jasmine

I recently joined on a project and I am very new to practically everything we're using. Currently I'm trying to set up some unit tests in Jasmine for out javascript code. I've been learning Jasmine for the past week or so and I've gotten some sample tests working on our server, but now I need to actually write tests, and I'm not sure how to write them correctly to test this behavior.

I'm starting in the collections, where we have code that looks like this:

```
define([…], function(…) {
  var measureModel = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    defaults: {…},
    initialize: function(){…}
    …
  });
  return measureModel;
});
```

How would I go about writing a test to make sure this behavior is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I testing plugin `blanket` - which count code coverage.

Please look that:

- http://piecioshka.pl/projects/test-blanket/app/
- http://piecioshka.pl/projects/test-blanket/test/

I feel thay meybe you should look for my traning project of Backbone:

- https://github.com/piecioshka/simple-backbone-app/

Feel free to let me know how it works!